# How to share functions in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

For example, I have a couple of functions written for my form. Now, I need the exact same functions in another form. So, how can I share them between the two forms? Please, provide a simple example if possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't put them in your form. Separate them and put them in a common unit, and add that unit to the `uses` clause where you need access to them.

Here's a quick example, but you can see many of the Delphi RTL units (for instance, `SysUtils`) that do this. (You should learn to use the VCL/RTL source and the demo apps that are included in Delphi; they could answer many of the questions you've posted more quickly than waiting for an answer here.)

SharedFunctions.pas:

```
unit 
  SharedFunctions;

interface

uses
  SysUtils;  // Add other units as needed

function DoSomething: string;

implementation

function DoSomething: string;
begin
  Result := 'Something done';
end;

end.
```

UnitA.pas

```
unit
  YourMainForm;

uses
  SysUtils;

interface

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)   
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    // other stuff
  end;

implementation

uses
  SharedFunctions;

procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(DoSomething());
end;

end.
```

In more recent versions of Delphi than Delphi 7, you can create the functions/methods in a `record` instead:

```
unit
  SharedFunctions;

interface

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TSharedFunctions = record
  public
    class function DoSomething: string;
  end;

implementation

function TSharedFunctions.DoSomething: string;
begin
  Result := 'Something done';
end;

end;
```

UnitB.pas

```
unit
  YourMainForm;

uses
  SysUtils;

interface

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)   
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    // other stuff
  end;

implementation

uses
  SharedFunctions;

procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(TSharedFunctions.DoSomething());
end;

end.
```

Comment: A self-explanatory answer. Should be the role model for SO writers. When programmers show patience with writing, its just otherworldly.

Comment: What if you want to create a global function or procedure which needs to have TForms as inputs? I tried this in a unit, not attached to a form and it couldn't do it as TForm wasn't defined...

procedure TfrmView.SwitchForm(Dest, Org: TForm);
begin
  Dest.Visible:=True;
  Org.Visible:=False;
end;

Comment: @JamesMcIntyre: Add `Forms` to the uses clause.

Comment: @KenWhite - thanks very much! I did perviously try adding TForm to the uses clause but I didn't know it was supposed to be just "Forms" but this worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you need forms. You could use inherited forms. Creating a form that inherit the functions of a parent form.

The most interesting. Any changes in the parent form is reflected a change in inherited forms. You even can inherit form controls (tbutton, tlabel, etc...).

In GUI Delphi7. Option "new form", option "inherited from a existing form".

Example:

```
//MainForm.pas
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm) 
     procedure MiFunction();
     .
     .
  end;

//ChilForm.pas
type
  TChildForm = class(TMainForm) 
  .
  .
  end;
```